# Site has white bars on top and bottom when viewed on a mobile device

Tags: html, css

https://ehguo.github.io/postknight/

When using the responsive design preview in either Chrome or Firefox, I do not get the white bars, but if visited on my actual phone, there are white bars.

[image]

Comment: Which phone are you using? Which browser are you using on said phone?

Comment: Moto Z Force, Chrome

Comment: Hmmm, if it's just specific to Chrome Mobile on my phone I guess I can ignore it.